# Accidental lightsaber injuries or deaths?

Tags: star-wars, jedi-training, lightsaber

Knowing that wielding lightsabers can be extremely dangerous to the uses, have there ever been any accidental, self-inflicted injuries or deaths caused to anyone?

Between the gyroscopic forces that using the lightsaber generates, and their unforgiving cutting potential, I would think their might have been a few "fails" or training/battle accidents.

Comment: I think it's the opposite is 'gyroscopic Forces'. They're light and easy to swing. Not that the rotational inertia (what you call gyroscopic forces) is high.

Comment: It depends. In Legends the blade is weightless, but in Disney canon it carries weight, so in current canon the blade does cause inertia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Legends novel ***Star Wars: Exile — Legacy of the Force*** by Aaron Allston, there are references to lightsaber accidents:

> "How *is* Zekk?" Kyp asked.
>
> Mara looked unconcerned.  "He'll make a full recovery. The surgeons on Hapes were very proficient. But he'll be out of action for a while." Her expression became concerned. "How many people know how it happened?"
>
> "Just me for the moment...I was assigned the investigation on this one." All **lightsaber accidents** that caused harm to a living being had to be looked into, and any Master on duty at the Temple might be randomly assigned the duty of investigation.

Later in the excerpt:

> "I'm just a little touchy I suppose. ***My* son has a lightsaber accident. Suddenly I feel the eyes of all the Jedi in the galaxy on me.**

Comment: There were a number of accidental dismemberments in the EU.